# My stylesheet doesn't apply on certain part of my code

Tags: html, css

Hi so I have a simple form with a table under with value coming from a db and when I  try to apply style via a stylesheet on the form it doesn't apply. But the style I've put for the button on the table under is applying.

Here's my code:

```
<?php
include('SQLFunction.php');
?>

<html>
<head>
    <title>CreateTask</title>
    <meta http-equiv=content-type content="text/html; charset=utf-8">

    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <link href="css/bootstrap-grid.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <link href="css/bootstrap-reboot.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css"/>

</head>
<body>
<span>
    <h1>New Task</h1>
    <form action="addTaskSubmit.php" method="POST" class="center" class="test">
        <div class="form-group row">
            <label class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Title: </label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
                <input class="form-control" type="text" name="TaskTitle" maxlenght='50' required>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group row">
            <label class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Description:</label>
            <textarea style="width:70%" type="text" class="form-control rounded-0" name='TaskDesc' rows="10"
                      maxlength='1000' required></textarea>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group row">
            <label class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Destination:</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
                <input class="form-control" type="text" name="TaskDest" maxlength="150">
            </div>
            <label class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Nextrun:</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
                <input class="form-control" type="datetime-local" name="TaskNextRun" required>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group row">
            <label class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Cron:</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
                <input class="form-control" type="text" name="TaskCron" maxlength="=50">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group row">
            <label class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Enabled</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
                <div class="form-check">
                    <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="TaskEnabled" id="gridRadios1" value="true"
                           required>
                    <label class="form-check-label" for="gridRadios1">Yes</label>
                </div>
                <div class="form-check">
                    <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="TaskEnabled" id="gridRadios1" value="false">
                    <label class="form-check-label" for="gridRadios1">No</label>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group row">
            <label class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">parentTicket:</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
                <input class="form-control" type="text" name="TaskParentTicket" maxlength="10">
            </div>
            <label class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">groupTicket:</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
                <input class="form-control" type="test" name="TaskGroupTicket" maxlength="150" required>
            </div>
            <label class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">lastCreatedTicket:</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
                <input class="form-control" type="text" name="TaskLastCreatedTicket" maxlength="10">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group row">
            <div class="col-sm-10">
                <button type="submit" name="addButton" class="btn btn-primary">Add</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</span>

<h1>IT Task Main View</h1>
<?php
$sql = "SELECT TOP 15 *
    from dbo.SCHEDULE
    order by id desc";

//echo '<br>Sql :' .$sql.'<br>We will comment this out after testing<br>';

$link = connectMSDB();

$getResult = $link->prepare($sql);
$getResult->execute();
$result = $getResult->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_BOTH);

echo "<div >";
echo "<table class=\"table table-hover\" style='width:85%; margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto;'>";
echo "<thead>";
echo "<tr>";
echo "<th>Action</th>";
echo "<th>Title</th>";
echo "<th>Description</th>";
echo "<th>Destination</th>";
echo "<th>Next Run</th>";
echo "<th>Cron</th>";
echo "<th>Enabled</th>";
echo "<th>Parent Ticket</th>";
echo "<th>Group Ticket</th>";
echo "<th>Last Created Ticket</th>";
echo "</tr>";
echo "</thead>";
echo "<tbody>";
foreach ($result as $row) {
    $desc = substr($row['description'], 0, 200);
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td><form action='UpdateTask.php' method='POST' onsubmit=''/><input type='hidden' name='q' value='" . $row['id'] . "'/>
                        <button type='submit' class=\"btn btn-update\" >Update</button></form>";

    echo "<form action='DeleteTask.php' method='POST' onsubmit=''/><input type='hidden' name='q' value='" . $row['id'] . "'/>
                        <button type='submit' class=\"btn btn-delete\" style=''>Delete</button></form></td>";
    echo "<td>{$row['title']}</td>";
    echo "<td>{$desc}</td>";
    echo "<td>{$row['destination']}</td>";
    echo "<td>{$row['nextrun']}</td>";
    echo "<td>{$row['cron']}</td>";
    echo "<td>{$row['enabled']}</td>";
    echo "<td>{$row['parentTicket']}</td>";
    echo "<td>{$row['groupTicket']}</td>";
    echo "<td>{$row['lastCreatedTicket']}</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</tbody>";
echo "</table>";
echo "</div>";

$link = null;
?>

<script src="js/bootstrap.bundle.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Here's my style sheet:

```
.btn-update {
    color:#004990;
    background-color: #F58020;
}

.btn-update:hover {
    background-color: #F8AA69;
    color: #3E5485
}

.btn-delete {
    color:#F58020;
    background-color:#004990;
}

.btn-delete:hover {
    background-color: #3E5485;
    color: #F8AA69;
}

.test{
    color: #FF0000;
}
```

So the class bnt-update, btn-update:hover, btn-delete and btn-delete:hover works but not the class test.

Strangely if I add the style directly in the form tag it works?

What I'm I doing wrong?

Thanks for the help

Comment: Post your rendered HTML. The PHP isn't relevant.

Comment: To apply two classes to an element you use: `class="center test"`. Your way is wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem here is found in the opening form tag. You have used the class attribute twice, when you should just be using it once and separated the classes by a space. The following should work:

```
<form action="addTaskSubmit.php" method="POST" class="center test">
```

Comment: @GabrielFournier of course! Did it work for you? If so, could you accept this as the answer by clicking the gray check mark on my answer? Thanks :D

Answer (score 1):

I noticed a few issues

- Instead of writing `class="center" class="test"`, write `class="center test"`
- You typed `type="test"` in `TaskGroupTicket` instead of `type="text"`
- You misspelled `maxlength` in `TaskTitle`
- You have the id `gridRadios1` twice. That is invalid HTML and it is causing your "No" `<label>` to check the "Yes" radio button